# Feedback on my solution "Determine a set compact or not"

Tags: general-topology

Let $X :=\{(x_1,0,x_2) \in \mathbb{R^3}, x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}\}$
$\mathcal{T}$ be subsapce topology coming from standard topology on $\mathbb{R^3}$.

My answer is that it's compact. Reason:

Define $f : \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2x_3$. This function is continuous. Now, restricting the domain to $X$, we have $f(X) = {0}$ which is also continuous. Now, $f^{-1} := \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} : f(x) \in \{0\} \}$ compact for codomain is Hausdorff . This pre-image contains X. and since $\{0\}$ is compact, then the pre-image is compact. Then its subset is compact? (this part confuses me, although, intuition tells me that, if a set of finite open covers covers big set, it undoubtedly covers the smaller one.)

Comment: Who told you that the pre-image of a compact set is compact? That's clearly not so. Let $X$ be any space whatever, define $f:X\to\Bbb R$ by $f(x)=0$; then it follows that _every_ space is compact. What??? What's true is that the _image_ of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich forget to mention that codomain should be Hausdorff

Comment: $X$ is unbounded.

Comment: Huh? I'm not sure whether you're saying you forgot to mention this or me. Doesn't matter - what you said is wrong whether the codomain is Hausdorff or not, and what I said is correct whether the codomain is Hausdorff or not. You're thinking of a different theorem...

Comment: Do you know Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: It is the otherway around, the image of a compact set is compact again, not the preimage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\Bbb R^3$, a set is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded, and your set there is not bounded. So it is **not** compact. Pre-images of compact sets by functions (even continuous ones) need not be compact, that's the mistake in your proof.

Comment: just one doubt. $A$ Closed and bounded iff $A$ compact. This works in $\mathbb{R^n}$. If the set is arbitrary Hausdorff set, the bounded definition must also holds?

Comment: How do you define "bounded" in an arbitrary topological space? You need a metric to do that.